# Trying to get WifiManger to update

Tags: android, wifi, wifimanager

I'm writing an app to view all wifi connections that are present. So far, i got it to to work somewhat.  When you press the submit button, you get a list of wifi connections, if you press it again, it will update the connections / values.  However any time you press it after that, the values dont update no more.  If someone could take a look at my method and lead me in the right direction, that would be great.  The source of the trouble is:

private void submitButton() { // Method that checks connections

```
    wInfo = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
    table.removeAllViewsInLayout(); // used to clear the table of the last update
    if(wifi.isWifiEnabled()){ // Check to make sure wifi is actually on
    List<ScanResult> sr = wifi.getScanResults(); 

    for(ScanResult scan : sr){
        // Custom Class to cut down on code
        TableAdapter ta = new TableAdapter(this, table);

        ta.addTableRow();
        ta.addImage(wifi, scan);
        ta.addTvN(this, scan);
        ta.addTvSi(this, scan);
        ta.addTvSp(this);
        ta.construct(); // Same as addView(Ojbect to add to view)

    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you need more of the code to look at, just let me know, i'll happily post it.

Comment: When you say that the values don't update anymore, what is it that is not updating, specifically?

Comment: The rows ta.addTableRow(); The images ta.addImage(); The network names ta.TvN(); and the Strength of the signal ta.TvSi();  the ta.addTvSp is just a spacer for now.

Comment: what is 'wInfo' about? it's referenced at the first line but nothing afterwards. Also, when it stops updating does it return the same old results or null?

Comment: that is used for the connection info that the device is currently connected to.  In this segment of the code, i suppose it is useless, because the same information is accuired throught the ScanResult List.  As you can probably tell, im very new at this but im trying :)

Comment: It seems that after more testing the code will actually continue to update when the submit button is pressed, however, you have to wait about 60 seconds or so before it will update again, no matter how many times your press the update button.  Is there some limit as to how the WifiManager class works?  Seems strange.

Comment: got it to work, surrounded the for statement with a if(wifi.startscan()) block.  Now its working great :)

Comment: I'm glad you found the answer to your problem. You should put that discovery in an answer and mark as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you want to retrieve new access point information you need to invoke [WifiManager.startScan()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#startScan%28%29).